# how to prevent images and css to be rewrite

Tags: .htaccess

I have some questions about `htaccess` ,
but first of all I want to apologize for my bad English.

I want to ask about `RewriteRule` .

1.If I want to to change my url extension , for example if I want my url to be `mysite.com/file.html` but the real url is `mysite.com/file.php` , how to do that ?

I used this code

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [R=301,L]
```

but when I tried it, I found that `.html` url redirect to `.php`

2.when I try to rewrite url from `http://mysite.com/file.php?varOne=something&varTwo=somethingelse`
to `http://mysite.com/file/something/somethingelse/`

all css,js and images don't appear bcz the dir changed ,

How can I prevent that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using `[L]` instead of `[R=301,L]`?

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

And when embedding CSS or images in your html, try to **begin with a slash** to get the files from the root directory:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />
```

The same with images:

```
<img src="/images/pic.png" alt="image" />
<img src="/mypic.png" alt="image" />
```

Comment: thank you ver much , i tried first one it's work , thanks so much , but the second issue , i cant fix it yet

Comment: you're welcome:) .. what have you tried so far?.. can you post a link to the site?

Answer (score 0):

Add the line:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

before all of your RewriteRule lines to prevent redirection for css, js and images.

Comment: Can you paste your entire .htaccess content to your question please.